# Registering MySQL DataSource with JNDI for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, jndi, dao

I have hibernate which connect to database via JNDI datasource.

My purpose: registry DataSource with JNDI to test DAO layer.

Example

Hibernate config

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="MySessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jdbc/MysqlMyDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<!-- mappings .... ->
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Get SessionFactory in test class :

```
Configuration cgf = new Configuration().configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory iceleadsSessionFactory = cgf.buildSessionFactory();
```

As the result:

```
16:04:37,753 ERROR DatasourceConnectionProvider:78 - Could not find datasource: java:jdbc/MysqlIceleadsDS
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

To register JNOI I use example (http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/registeringthedatasourcewithjndi.html)

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class RegisteringJNDIWithDataSource {
        private static void startRegistry() throws RemoteException {
                System.out.println(LocateRegistry.getRegistry());
                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1059);
                System.out.println("RMI registry Stared.");
        }

        private static InitialContext createInitialContextContext()
                        throws NamingException {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                                "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
                properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://localhost:1059");
                InitialContext initialContextcontext = new InitialContext(properties);
                return initialContextcontext;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                try {
                        startRegistry();
                        ConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
                        ((MysqlDataSource) dataSource).setUser("root");
                        ((MysqlDataSource) dataSource).setPassword("root");
                        ((MysqlDataSource) dataSource).setServerName("192.168.10.13");
                        ((MysqlDataSource) dataSource).setPort(3306);
                        ((MysqlDataSource) dataSource).setDatabaseName("student");

                        InitialContext context = createInitialContextContext();
                        context.rebind("Source", dataSource);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
}
```

Please suggest solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you change the type of `dataSource` to `MysqlDataSource`? you could then get rid of those 5 casts.

Comment: I tried to use DataSource (not MysqlDataSource) but the same result. Problem that hibernate Could not find any datasource

Comment: have you set `jndi.properties` for test environment? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work, if you correctly set `jndi.properties`. This file should be in classpath.

here is working example:

Server:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        ConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = createDataSource("root", "");

        InitialContext context = createContext();
        context.bind("MysqlMyDS", dataSource);
        System.out.println("context created!");

    }

    private static InitialContext createContext() throws NamingException {
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://localhost:1099");
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
        return context;
    }

    private static ConnectionPoolDataSource createDataSource(String username, String password) {
        MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setPort(3306);
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("test");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

client:

hibernate.cfg.xml Note: datasource jndi name should be exactly as you set it by `context.bind()`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">MysqlMyDS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

jndi.properties (if you want, you can set it in code or with -D option)

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=rmi://localhost:1099
```

unit test

```
public class TestClient {
    @Test
    public void testCfg() throws Exception {
        Configuration cgf = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        cgf.buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```