# How registry JNDI datasource for JUnit for Jboss environment

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, jboss, jndi

Project use Hibernate and deployed on Jboss 5.1. Hibernate uses JNDI to get datasource.

I want create JUnit tests for DAO layer and for this I need create JNDI data source and transaction manager to test without running Jboss.

For this I wrote the code:

```
System.out.println(LocateRegistry.getRegistry());
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);


Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");

InitialContext initialContextcontext = new InitialContext(properties);
```

When I try to lookup or bind the named object application is frizz. And after some time throw timeout exception. Bind subcontext throws the same exception

In Maven I include dependency:

```
  <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
```

After research I have faced with this article http://something-about-tech.blogspot.com/2008/12/injecting-jndi-datasource-for-junit.html . But there the line like this `Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);` is missed.. I in confusion...

In related post ([Registering MySQL DataSource with JNDI for Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419762/registering-mysql-datasource-with-jndi-for-hibernate)) I have interested about registry datasource but there was

```
Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY="com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory` is JBoss specific protocol, you cannot use it to connect to RMI registry. Try this test

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable, Remote {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.bind("rmi://localhost/xxx", new Test1());
        Test1 t1 = (Test1) ctx.lookup("rmi://localhost/xxx");
        System.out.println(t1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. but how I must bind? I tried put properties PROVIDER_URL= "rmi://localhost:1099" but got exception "Failed to connect to server". could you explain in more details, please?

Comment: Actually, if you have a DataSource why bind? Why not use it directly?

Comment: Thanks, looks it's ok now. I bind DataSource because hibernate conf use jndi to get it. so, for test purpose I need bind DataSource to test the same things as for production. Thanks again for your help.